# How do I fetch the values of an entity's field?

Tags: nodes, 8, database

How to query all the values of a particular field. I used `Drupal\Core\Database\Connection object` to fetch the values as below:

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$result = $connection->select('node__body', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('body_value'))
  ->execute()->fetchCol();
```

Is there any Drupal 8 API specifically for this?  I need to fetch all values of the field and fetch the field values for a particular node bundle.

Comment: There is no API for this.The only official API is loading the entities.

Comment: So what I am doing is right?

Comment: No, it's not "right". You shouldn't be doing it, there is no guarantee that it will continue to work or will return correct results. If you do anything like that, you're on your own.

Comment: So in order fetch all field values, should I load entities in which it is present?

Answer (score 7):

In Drupal 7, you would use the [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class. In Drupal 8, there is an equivalent service.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('changed', REQUEST_TIME, '<')
    ->condition('title', 'cat', 'CONTAINS')
    ->condition('field_tags.entity.name', 'cats');

$nids = $query->execute();
```

In your case, instead of field_tag.entity.name, you need body.body_value. See [EntityFieldQuery has been rewritten](https://www.drupal.org/node/1827278).
If you just need to get all the node IDs, remove all the `condition()` lines, and then use `entity_load_multiple('node', $nids)` to load the full node objects.

In this way, your code is not making assumptions about the tables used to contain the node data. Plus, it can be easily extended to filter the nodes basing on some criteria (node properties, content of fields...).

Comment: I think this will return nids of the nodes satisfying the condition but my need is to fetch all the field values in a particular content type.

Comment: Once you have the node IDs, you can load the full node objects.

Comment: Instead of removing all conditions (which will load all nodes - which could be a lot), you presumably would want to use `->exists('field_name')`. @see http://drupalsun.com/zhilevan/2017/01/14/query-drupal-8-entityquery

Answer (score 5):

Although [entityQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8) is very powerful I believe not everything can and should be done with it. Loading all nodes to get the values might consume to much resources. Using the [Database API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api) should be fine with some help of the [TableMappingInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Sql!TableMappingInterface.php/interface/TableMappingInterface/8), as stated in the documentation:

> Provides a common interface for mapping field columns to SQL tables.
>
> Warning: using methods provided here should be done only when writing code that is explicitly targeting a SQL-based entity storage. Typically this API is used by SQL storage classes, or other SQL-specific code like the Views integration code for the Entity SQL storage. Another example of legal usage of this API is when needing to write a query that \Drupal::entityQuery() does not support.

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\TableMappingInterface $table_mapping*/
$table_mapping = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getTableMapping();

$field_table = $table_mapping->getFieldTableName('field_categories');
$field_storage_definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldStorageDefinitions('node')['field_categories'];
$field_column = $table_mapping->getFieldColumnName($field_storage_definitions, 'target_id');

$connection = \Drupal::database();
$result = $connection->select($field_table, 'f')
  ->fields('f', array($field_column))
  ->distinct(TRUE)
  ->condition('bundle', 'article')
  ->condition('entity_id', $nids, 'IN')
  ->execute()->fetchCol();
```

*This works so far. But there are still asumptions about the columns `bundle` and `entity_id`. I am not sure if it would be save to assume that they will be allways there. Maybe there are also functions to get the bundle and the entity-id column, but I guess not, because it seems that views makes the same asumptions, see [views_field_default_views_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.views.inc/function/views_field_default_views_data/8).*