# Display latest three news on a custom template

Tags: 8, theming

I'm building a **custom theme** and I would like to display last three inserted news (i.e. nodes with content type = *News*) <s>on the bottom of the home page</s> from inside the home page template.

Something like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
| +---------------------------+ |
| |                           | |
| |          Slides           | |
| |                           | |
| +---------------------------+ |
|                               |
| +---------------------------+ |
| |                           | |
| |           Page            | |
| |           Body            | |
| |                           | |
| |                           | |
| +---------------------------+ |
|                               |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
| | Last  | |Second | | Third | |
| | News  | | Last  | | Last  | |
| |       | | News  | | News  | |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
+-------------------------------+
```

I created a content type named *Home page*, with fields for manage slides and the page body, then I created a new content (a new node) of type *Home page*.

Inside my custom theme I created a template file named `node--home-page.html.twig` and inside it I can handle the *Home page*'s fields (slides and body) and how to render them inside the page.

After that I created another content type *News* and I added some content of such type.

Now I would like to display latest news inside the homepage template as in the figure above. What is the *better*/*simplest* way to do it?

I'm thinking to load latest news in some `hook_preprocess_HOOK` function (using the [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162532/fetch-field-values-in-drupal-8) object) then add them inside a variable for the Twig template. Inside the template I will perform a `for` loop rendering latest news at the page's bottom. Is this a good way to do it or I'm completely out of the way?

---

**EDIT**

*Correction*: I would like to display latest news between slides and body, in this way:

```
+-------------------------------+
| +---------------------------+ |
| |                           | |
| |          Slides           | |
| |                           | |
| +---------------------------+ |
|                               |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
| | Last  | |Second | | Third | |
| | News  | | Last  | | Last  | |
| |       | | News  | | News  | |
| +-------+ +-------+ +-------+ |
|                               |
| +---------------------------+ |
| |                           | |
| |           Page            | |
| |           Body            | |
| |                           | |
| |                           | |
| +---------------------------+ |
+-------------------------------+
```

Where `slides` and `body` are two fields of the *Home page* content type.

Comment: Have you thought about including a view in `config/install` with a block display, and a grid style that is positioned in your custom region?

Comment: @mradcliffe Thank you for your suggestion. No, I didn't thought about views and blocks. I would like to keep it as simple as possible. Do you think it is a bad approach fetching latest news from a preprocess function? Otherwise, do you have a reference with an example where I could learn more about how to do it with a view?

Comment: It doesn't get much easier than a View providing a block display, and putting the block in that region set for the front page only (or alternatively, that content type).

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. I'm trying to do it with Views and Blocks now. But I need to display the view's content (latest news) in the middle of the *Home page*'s content (see my last edit on the question), between two fields of the *Home page* node. Do you have any idea on how I could do it inside a custom template?

Comment: It is impractical to put regions into a node template. You might want to try creating a reference field for that block/view and theme the result. This is something Paragraphs was designed for to excel at doing. Another way to do this would be to make a Content Top region and Content Main and Content Bottom, that way you can put blocks above or below the main content output.

Comment: @Kevin Doing it with Paragraphs seems a good solution for me since I'm already using it.. But I can't understand how to use it in this case. How can I create a reference field and connect it with a view?

Comment: You should be able to add a entity reference field on the content type and select a View (or maybe) block... I have done it before but don't recall which one you pick. Then the field should let you select which view or block to show.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin for your help. I ended up to embed a view inside the template using this (new) module: https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak, with `{{ drupal_view('view_name') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module and I embedded a custom view, showing latest news, inside my Twig template with:

```
{{ drupal_view('view_name') }}
```